# Install default Android 2.2 / 2.3 on Optimus One

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rom-flashing, rom, lg-optimus-one

I have this [LG Optimus One P500h](http://www.lg.com/uk/mobile-phones/all-lg-phones/LG-android-mobile-phone-P500.jsp) and I was thinking about formatting and installing the default/original **Android 2.2** (2.3 would be great) since LG modified the homescreen, keyboard and other stuffs.

Is this possible? Is this safe? Is this insane?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

There's a "beta" version of CyanogenMod 7 for the Optimus One over at [the XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=946354) which you could try out. There also appear to be a couple of builds that are derived from CM but mix in different tweaks and patches to the kernel and whatnot (one such build [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=909242), also Gingerbread).

[CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) - if you're not already familiar with it - is essentially a vanilla Android experience but with some nice additional settings and improvements. They build from the Android source code and then add some patches of their own. I think one of the few plainly noticeable differences is that they use ADW Launcher as a home app instead of the stock Gingerbread one, but I think the GB launcher is floating around on the Market somewhere. ADW is nice anyway, though.